# I can't catch InputMismatchException

Tags: java

I get InputMismatchException error as I wanted,but can't catch it.(I am doing this just to learn it)
Can anybody help me?

```
package GameProject;
import java.util.*;
public class Execute {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
      boolean enemySelected=false;
      boolean characterSelected=false;
      do {              
          System.out.println("Choose your character!");
          System.out.println("1-Knight\n2-Tank\n3-Warrior");
          int choosenCharacter=scan.nextInt();
              try{

                if(choosenCharacter==1|| choosenCharacter==2||choosenCharacter==3) {
                    characterSelected=true;
                }   
            
              }
              catch(InputMismatchException   e) {
                
                 System.out.println("Choosen character doesn't exists.Try again!");
                
              }   
               
              
      }while(characterSelected==false);
      
    }

}
```

Comment: `scan.nextInt();` throws it, not the code you have currently wrapped within the `try catch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An exception is captured only if the statement that produce the exception is inside a try-catch statement.

You need to place `int choosenCharacter=scan.nextInt();` inside the `try` block, and then the exception will be captured by the `catch`

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
int choosenCharacter=scan.nextInt();
```

that needs to go INSIDE the try block!

It doesn't help to do a *try* after the expression that can cause the exception. The code that can throw needs to be *enclosed* with try/catch.

Comment: thanks,but now it is in infinitive loop :) Any suggestion?

Comment: Ok,I add scan.nextLine() to catch and solved